# Inserir nome de cidade em uma Search box e abrir mapa dessa cidade em outra página

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Bom, sou iniciante na área e gostaria de um auxílio dos mais experientes. Estou iniciando um projeto que tem por finalidade o uso do Google Maps para apresentar um local baseado em uma consulta por search box pelo usuário. Possuo uma tabela chamada clientes no Mysql e gostaria de obter uma orientação. A princípio a ideia será mais ou menos assim:

1. Na página principal do site exemplo terá no centro da página principal um campo Search box. O usuário digita a cidade no campo como na imagem exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Após o usuário ter clicado no botão buscar, uma página é aberta com um mapa do Google Maps referente a cidade que o usuário digitou no campo de busca e ao mesmo tempo a página conteria os dados de clientes referentes a aquela cidade pesquisada.  Veja uma imagem exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso como posso fazer visto que possuo uma tabela chamada "Clientes" no Mysql e um código API Javascript do Google Maps que foi gerado?

Desde já agradeço pela atenção. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o LINK do Google abaixo sem necessariamente ter uma API.

A variável Local seria o que você digitar no campo. Fiz o exemplo simples abaixo que carrega o LINK do Google com o local digitado em um Link para abrir numa página externa.

```
https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/' + local
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById('search');
var linkMaps = document.getElementById('linkMap');


button.addEventListener("click", searchMaps);

function searchMaps() {
  var local = document.getElementById('local').value;
  linkMaps.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/' + local);
}
```

```html
<label>Digite a cidade:</label>
<input type="text" name="local" id="local">
<button id="search">Acessar</button>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" id="linkMap" target="_blank"> Ver Maps </a>
```